# How to Convert a folder of csv files to json files within Jekyll

Tags: jekyll

Is it possible to convert a folder of csv files to json as part of a Jekyll workflow? I currently use a python script to do this but would like to do it entirely within Jekyll

Answer (score 0):

You can call your python script as part of the build process, but you'll have to make a teeny tiny plugin to do it. This also assumes you're not using github pages, because they don't like plugins.

1. make a `_plugins` directory in your site root.
2. Inside that directory, create `csv_to_json.rb`
3. In that ruby file, call your python script with the following code:

```rb
# The following line tells jekyll to run everything between 'do' and 'end'
# when it finishes writing the site to disk:
Jekyll::Hooks.register :site, :post_write do |_site|

  # Backticks are one way to call shell commands from ruby: 
  `python your_script_here.py` # replace with the correct filename
end
```

This is untested code. Relevant documentation [here](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/hooks/) and [here](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/installation/)

There are quite a few ways to do this, but I think that's the simplest for your case.

Answer (score 0):

You can :

1 - Store your csv in _data/foldername (eg : _data/members) see : [Jekyll's data files](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/datafiles/)

2 - Put all your datas in a new array with `concat` [filter](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/filters/)

```
{% comment %} ### Create an empty array{% endcomment %}
{% assign all-members = "" | split: "" %}
{% for part in site.data.members %}
  {% assign all-members = all-members | concat: part[1] %}
{% endfor %}
```

3 - Output datas unsing the jsonify filter : `{{ all-members | jsonify }}`

An all in one, a members.json file can look like :

```
---
layout: null
---
{% assign all-members = "" | split: "" %}
{%- for part in site.data.members %}
{% assign all-members = all-members | concat: part[1] %}
{% endfor -%}
{{ all-members | jsonify }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to both of you. I have gone the plugin route as this is the easiest and I may need to develop another plugin at some point so I may as well learn how to make one.